# In Robocraft, how do you spawn a robot to practice against in testing mode?

Tags: robocraft

There is a testing mode, where you spawn in an outdoor area with mountains, some targets, and some obstacles. How do you spawn a robot to spar with in that mode?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware this isn't a feature (yet); however you can always take your bot into PvE mode and play against a whole host of different AI bots.